# problem with non linear pde

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, mp.mathematical-physics

I have the following pde which i cannot solve. any suggestions, tips on how to approach a solution?

$$\left(1-x^3 \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \partial_{y}\right) f(y(x))-1/4 \left(1-\frac{1}{x^3 (\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})} \partial_y\right) (\partial_y f(y(x)))^2 =b^2$$
or in a cleaner way:
$$ \left(1-w(y)\partial_y\right)f(y)-1/4\left(1-\frac{1}{w(y)}\partial_y \right) \left(\partial_y f(y)\right)^2=b^2 $$
with 
$$ w(y)=x^3\frac{\partial y}{\partial x},  \ \ y=y(x),  \ \ b=const. $$

--Edited from comments---
This question comes from a problem in classical general relativity, involving an Ad$S_5$ background metric. The differential equation comes from trying to embed a string in this background. The function $f$ is related to the shape of the string, whereas $y$ and $x$ are related to the worldsheet coordinates. The unknowns are both $f$, and $y$.

Comment: You're solving for both $f$ and $y$?

Comment: What is the unknown function here, f(y) or y(x)? Either way, this looks like an ODE, not a PDE.

Comment: Where in blazes did you get such a monster?

Comment: yes, i want to solve both for $f(y)$ and $y(x)$

Comment: Will Jagy: Im not an undergraduate and this is not a problem derived from an undergraduate course.  

Comment: Dear Regina, I think your problem is quite interesting and so I feel motivated to do something I normally wouldn't be so concerned with, and that is to ask you to add a few words addressing the origins of this problem. I'm pretty sure many would agree doing so would help people help you in your search for an answer.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that it has a solution that you can actually write down? You're really not telling us much about this problem and its origins!

Comment: To tell you about the origins of the problem: Im a physicist and doing a calculation in classical GR; a problem involving an AdS_5 background metric. The differential equation comes from trying to embed a string in this background. The function $f$ is related to the shape of the string, $y, x$ are related to the worldsheet coordinates.
I could say more, but that would go beyond explaining where that equation comes from. 
As said: Id be thankful about any help. I have a feeling that there should be a way to solve this but am not mighty enough to do so.

Comment: hum... if you are just interested in finding a solution to this ODE, you can of course set $w(y) = 1$ by solving $dy/dx = 1/x^3$. Then you can reduce using integrating factor to the equation $$ f(y) - \frac14 (df/dy)^2 = b^2 + C e^y$$ where $C$ is some free constant. The case $C= 0$ is readily solved. I'm not sure if there are any nice closed-form solutions when $C\neq 0$. 